# How can implement a question answer logic in front end as well as back end

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, model, logic

In my website I am gonna show a main question with some answers.

So if the user clicks one of the answers I am gonna show some list of questions again with respective answers.So each answers has got certain questions again .This process goes on till there is a answer which has got no questions. How I can i do it most efficiently on the server side in java as well as on the html side . How can i store this structure in some model.

If anybody knows any kind of opensource project which implement this logic please help.

Comment: In your example you mention that if a user clicks an answer, a list of questions along with answers will be displayed. What I am wondering, is when you click on an answer, how will the corresponding questions that are displayed going to be related? For example, are they going to share a similar topic, or will these questions be questions asked based on the answer?

Comment: ya u r right ! but i don't know how..?

Comment: I did not mean in terms of a data structure. What I meant was are they going to share a similar topic, or will these questions be questions asked based on the answer?

Comment: ya if there if certain questions present for an answer in the backed xml file yes...

Comment: I am still confused by what you mean, could you explain in a little more detail how questions and answers are tied together? also what background xml file do you mean? will these questions and responses not be stored dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you would need a tree:

- A question would be represented as a node
- An answer is an edge leading from one question to another
- An answer not leading to a new question, would simply have the destination node as null.

In Java you would could represent it like this:

```
class Question {
    
    // The question, for example "What is the color of the sky?"
    String question;
    
    // List of answer alternatives: For example
    //     - Blue (with destination, "What is the color of the sun?")
    //     - Red  (with destination null)
    List<Answer> answers;
    
}


class Answer {
    
    // The answer, for example "Blue"
    String answer;
    
    // The next question (or null, if this answer is terminating)
    Question destinationQuestion;
}
```

To create a full tree of these objects, you need to either

- Provide constructors that takes one argument per attribute

  In such case you need to build the tree from the leaves up (since you can't provide intermediate nodes with their arguments unless you've already created them)
- Create "setter"-methods, create all questions and "set" the appropriate children where they are supposed to be. (This would allow you to build the tree from root to leaves.)

---

Other alternatives:

- You could use a DAG (directed acyclic graph) if you would like to reuse parts of the tree in several places (i.e., if several answers leads to the same answer)
- You could use an ordinary directed graph if you would like to allow for cycles in the question system.

In either way the two classes I described above fits the bill!

Comment: ya i thought of once but I am a newbie...looks quite complicated to me..don't know how to start... :(

Comment: answers can also have multiple questions again.

Comment: Then replace `Question destinationQuestion` with `List<Question> destinationQuestions`.

Comment: You simply create the objects and populate the `List<Answer>` with the "child" questions / answers. The tree structure is a set of objects referring to each other.

Comment: any demo code would be great like u created something for question and answer.

Comment: and i don't think there is anything bad in helping the people who r new and somehow don't have so much grip on the language..

Comment: well I everybody knows basic but u learn through solving complex problems like these

Comment: As a good exercise I suggest you write your own single linked list with basic append / remove operations.

Comment: I knew that already....I wanted to do this exercise now...what the problem with it...